# IIS ISSUE Backup and Restore

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I want to restore  IIS from Windows Server 2008 Standard 32 Bit to 64 Bit Windows Server 2008 R2,We want to backup and restore.WE already used appcmd to take backup and restore. But given error : Error( hrresult:80070005, message : command execution failed .Access Denied), Please help in this regards .Send me step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the appcmd command as administrator.Or you can open powershell run as admin and execute below command:-

appcmd add backup backup_name
appcmd restore backup backup_name

When you wll open powershell it will open with C:\windows\syatem32\

Kepp location as it is and execute the command.

Let me know if you face any issue.